# Show "dropdown" attribute type on product grid

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute, product-listing

I have a product attribute for configurable products as a "dropdown" and I would like to show it on product listing/grid how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

set this in the attribute creation. 'used_in_product_listing' => true,

```
 <?php
  namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Setup;

  use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
  use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
  private $eavSetupFactory;

  public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
  {
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
  }

  public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
  {
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'sample_attribute',
        [
            'type' => 'int',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Sample Atrribute',
            'input' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The attribute was created from admin, it is set to Yes for Used in product Listing

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by admin configuration. Please traverse to

admin panel ->Stores ->Product ->Your attribute ->StoreFront properties ->Used in Product Listing ->Yes

Clear cache and run indexing and check the grid.

Hope it helps !

Comment: The attribute is set to Yes for Used in product Listing but it only shows if is a swatch